# Set Batch Size *and* Number of Training Iterations for a neural network?

Tags: neural-network, doc2vec, knime

I am using the KNIME Doc2Vec Learner node to build a Word Embedding. I know how Doc2Vec works. In KNIME I have the option to set the parameters

- Batch Size:  The number of words to use for each batch.
- Number of Epochs: The number of epochs to train.
- Number of Training Iterations: The number of updates done for each batch.

From Neural Networks I know that (lazily copied from https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/153531/what-is-batch-size-in-neural-network):

- one **epoch** = one forward pass and one backward pass of *all* the training examples
- **batch size** = the number of training examples in one forward/backward pass. The higher the batch size, the more memory space you'll need.
- number of **iterations** =  number of passes, each pass using [batch size] number of examples. To be clear, one pass = one forward pass + one backward pass (we do not count the forward pass and backward pass as two different passes).

As far as I understand it makes little sense to set batch size *and* iterations, because one is determined by the other (given the data size, which is given by the circumstances). So why can I change both parameters?

Answer (score 1):

This is not necessarily the case. You can also train "half epochs". For example, in Google's inceptionV3 pretrained script, you usually set the **number of iterations** and the **batch size** at the same time. This can lead to "partial epochs", which can be fine.

If it is a good idea or not to train half epochs may depend on your data. There is a [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43681853/why-not-train-for-partial-epochs) about this but not a concluding answer.

I am not familiar with KNIME Doc2Vec, so I am not sure if the meaning is somewhat different there. But from the definitions you gave setting batch size + iterations seems fine. Also setting number of epochs could cause conflicts though leading to situations where numbers don't add up to reasonable combinations.

Comment: I do not understand what the number of epochs `E` have to do with this. Let's say I have `N=1000` training samples. Then an epoch is how often I train on those 1000 samples. Let's say have `I=5` iterations, then I the batch size is `B = N/I = 200` - no `E` involved. Alternatively I can fix the batch size to 120 and have `I = N/B = 8.3`, so I have 8 full iterartions with 120 samples and on iteration with 40 samples. Still no `E` involved. Now I set `I=5` and `B=100` - this cannot be reconciled, leading to my original question.

Comment: Can you provide any code or more information about the NN you are using? Without it its impossible to say why and how those parameters are used exactly.

Comment: KNIME falls back on the implementation from DL4J: https://deeplearning4j.org/doc2vec. You can also check out https://deeplearning4j.org/word2vec, which is rather similar.